# TypeError in opencv object detection

Tags: python, opencv

Detection with the below code doesn't work. Execution stops after 5 seconds with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1),(x,y+h),font,(0,255,255))
TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

How to solve this error?

This is my code:

```
"""
Created on Sat Apr  6 09:53:56 2019

@author: lenovo
"""

import cv2
import numpy as np

lowerBound=np.array([85,153,50])
upperBound=np.array([255,255,255])
cam= cv2.VideoCapture(1)

kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while True:
    ret, img=cam.read()
    img=cv2.resize(img,(340,220))

    #convert BGR to HSV
    imgHSV= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # create the Mask
    mask=cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)
    #morphology
    maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
    maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)

    maskFinal=maskClose
    _,conts,h=cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cv2.drawContours(img,conts,-1,(255,0,0),3)
    for i in range(len(conts)):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(i+1),(x,y+h),font,(0,255,255))
    cv2.imshow("maskClose",maskClose)
    cv2.imshow("maskOpen",maskOpen)
    cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
    cv2.imshow("cam",img)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

According [to the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.putText) `putText` has the following signature:

```
cv2.putText(img, text, org, fontFace, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]]) → None
```

This means that you're missing a mandatory double argument `fontScale` (that's what your colour tuple is being interpreted as, hence the error). You need to provide this, I suspect `1.0` is a reasonable first choice:

> fontScale – Font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific base size.

assuming that the base size is something reasonable (you'll have to end up playing with the font size anyway).